# Using jquery to swap out contents of a div

Tags: jquery, html

I have this bit of html:

```
<div id="storeBtn">
    <a href="http://itunes.apple.com/artist" target="itunes_store" class="button">Download on iTunes</a>
</div>
```

If I detect Android, I want to change it to this:

```
<div id="storeBtn">
    <a href="http://amazon.com/artist" class="button">Download on Amazon</a>
</div>
```

This is my attempt:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
$("#storeBtn").html("<a href='http://amazon.com/artist' class='button'>Download on Amazon</a>");

}
```

But nothing changes. I also tried replaceWith() instead of html().

Comment: Do you wait for the dom to be ready ? Did you check the value of isAndroid ?

Comment: Are you positive that what you are using is an android?  If you are testing on a pc without a user-agent changer, then no dice.

Comment: have you checked if isAndroid is true ?

Comment: Yes, I can display an alert if isAndroid.

Comment: What does your js console tell you? is $ defined? Did you try setting a breakpoint?

Comment: i'm testing on an Android device so I don't really have access to consoles. I can only pop up alerts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put your code in the head section but in a script element at the end of the body.

```
...

<script>
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
    $("#storeBtn").html("<a href='http://amazon.com/artist' class='button'>Download on Amazon</a>");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When your code is in the head, it's executed before the addition of your div to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

This code needs to wait for the Dom to be ready before execution:

```
$(function() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); 
    var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile"); 
    if(isAndroid) { 
        $("#storeBtn").html("<a href='http://amazon.com/artist' class='button'>Download on Amazon</a>"); 

    } 
}
```

Comment: I tried this and still nothing happens, and in fact if I put an alert to check isAndroid it doesn't fire. I should just be able to put your code in the head section right?